# can I make 'pull to refresh' action if my view controller is not scrollable?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

I have an UIViewController, and in its `viewDidLoad` I retrieve an employee data from a server. but sometimes we may have internet connection issue, and unfortunately the next step depends on this employee data. so I have to make sure this employee data is not nil before doing segue to the next view controller.

when the connection issue occurred, this employee data will be nil. at this time I will instruct the user to do 'Pull to refresh'. I have tried to implement pull to refresh in my view controller, but it doesn't work since UIViewController is not scrollable.

can I implement pull to refresh in my UIViewController?

because I think it is easier to just pull to refresh then push 'special button' that appears only to refresh to get the emlpoyee data. or is there a better/common  way to tackle this issue?

pull to refresh in TableViewController is like this, but how about in UIViewController

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


    var arrayNumber = [1,2,3,4]
    var refresher : UIRefreshControl! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        refresher = UIRefreshControl()
        refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "please pull to refresh")
        refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableViewController.populateTableView), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)


        tableView.addSubview(refresher)




    }



    @objc func populateTableView() {
        for i in 1...100 {
            arrayNumber.append(i)
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
        refresher.endRefreshing() 
    }




    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayNumber.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tabCell", for: indexPath)


        cell.textLabel?.text = String(arrayNumber[indexPath.row])

        return cell

    }


}
```

Comment: I have never used UIRefreshControl, but isn't it tableView.refreshControl = refresher as opposed to tableView.addSubview(refresher) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented something like that in a previous project. Unfortunately UIRefresh Control only works with object that inherent from UIScrollView.

But with that being said, I just created a custom view that contains a UIActivityView and (whatever else you imagination desires). Then in the ViewController we added a swipe gesture that will display our custom view.

One more thing I would like to mention to get the same visual effect as a UIRefreshControl, you can add the custom view as a subview of your viewControllers view and set the y: value to -the subview height. Then when the user swipes down you can animate the `view.transform = CGAffinetransform(translate: 0, customView.hieght)` this would cause the main view to appear as if it scrolled down with the users swipe and the custom refreshcontrol will appear.